# How i can Optimise my code in javascript (inutile foreach)

Tags: javascript, frontend

I created a code in JS which is used to change a word at regular intervals.
I was told there was a problem with the optimization, for exemple, at my foreach, I was told that I don't need it but I don't understand, someone could explain to me where is a problem ?

```
export default class Keywords {
    constructor() {
        this.keywordsWrapper = document.querySelector('.js-keywords-wrapper');
        if (this.keywordsWrapper) {
            this.init();
        }
    }

    init() {
        this.items = document.querySelectorAll('.js-keywords-item');
        this.currentWordId = 0;
        if (this.items.length) {
            this.items.forEach((item, index) => {
                if (index === 0) {
                    item.classList.add('active');
                }
            });
        }
        this.turnWords();
    }
    
    turnWords() {
        setTimeout(() => { 
            const itemsLength = this.items.length;
            
            if (this.currentWordId === this.items.length) {
                this.currentWordId = 0;
            }
            this.items.forEach((item) => {
                item.classList.remove('active');
            });
            
            for (let i = 0; i < itemsLength; i++) {
                if (i === this.currentWordId) {
                    this.items[i].classList.add('active');
                }
            }

            this.currentWordId ++;

            this.turnWords();
        }, 3000);
    }
}
```

```
@foreach ($keywords as $keyword)
    <a href={{ $keyword['url'] }} @if (!empty($keyword['new_tab'])) target="_blank"@endif
     class="js-keywords-item">{{ $keyword['text'] }}</a>
@endforeach
```

Comment: It's courtesy to include html also to provide a reproducible example. On the textarea toolbar of the question edit is an icon with `<>` on it that will provide a code editor that makes it easier for folks helping to copy into their own answer and check results live while editing. Cheers

Comment: So, somebody told you "You don't need forEach", but didn't tell you why? My guess is, at `if (index === 0)`. You are iterating the whole array, and testing for each element if it's the first one (index 0). If it is, `add('active')`, if it's not, keep iterating. That's indeed very heavy, you don't need to iterate your whole array and test each item one by one. Just take the first element in the array with `this.items[0].classList.add('active')`, job done

Comment: I was told that it was better to declare my items directly, that my foreach was useless in this cause, but i dont see how it can work

Comment: Ok thanks you, I understand better, and I do the same for the other

Comment: For the second one, we can't do it like that ?